# Stackdriver Trace on GKE with Python app aggregates metrics in one collection

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, opencensus

I am preparing a demo on GKE with an simple server app written in python that gets the requests from an Envoy proxy, and adds some delay.

I wanted to use Stackdriver Trace to show the delay applied by each Envoy proxy and the app, but what I am getting is not that attractive visually.

So, there is this Envoy proxy that proxies the request to 3 different apps, called blue, green and red. Each of them also has an Envoy proxy that adds a delay and sends the request to the Python server that returns a simple "Hello ...".

I sent 1000 requests to the front service that randomly forwarded these request to the 3 apps. Now when I go to Stackdriver Trace console, this is what I see:

[image]

When I click on each of them (say green), I can see all the requests accumulated under green, with the time it took to respond for each request:

[image]

So, all these seems to be fine, but from the point of view of the demo, it is not that attractive to show this dashboard. If I send only few requests, it sometimes is not gathering, and the trace never shows up on the dashboard. I was wondering if there is a way to have these requests broken down to 1. So I will have a dashboard similar to this one (from Stackdriver Examples):

[image]

...where each request seems to be 1 dot, and I can just click on it and get the info.

Again, my demo is with Python, and it is in Alpha.

Comment: The question is unclear - are you looking for a way to have more samples in the trace list? You can simply generate requests over a period of time to have that view fill up.  Or are you looking to not have the trace propagation work the way it's working currently?

Comment: that's exactly my issue. As the second screenshot shows, all the requests I do go under one dot.

Comment: How are you creating traces? Is your app instrumented with the Stackdriver Trace agent?